# What is the quantum capacity of the combined amplitude and phase damping channel?

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, decoherence, channel-capacity

Quantum capacity for the amplitude damping channel and the pure dephasing channel have closed-form formulas as it can be seen in section 24.7.2 of [From Classical to Quantum Shannon Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1445.pdf). However, I am unsure if there exist such a result for the more complete decoherence model that combines both actions into the combined amplitude and phase damping channel. This is a Kraus rank $3$ quantum channels with the following error operators
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ampphaseKraus}
\begin{aligned} E_0 &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma-(1-\gamma)\lambda} 
\end{pmatrix} \\ 
\\E_1 &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{\gamma} \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\\E_2 &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{(1-\gamma)\lambda} 
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is the damping parameter and $\lambda$ is the scattering parameter. This channel can be seen as the serial composition of the composing ampitude damping channel and dephasing channel as $\mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{APD}}=\mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{PD}}\circ \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{AD}}$. I am wondering if there is some known result on the capacity of this channel, as it happens for its constituting channels.